# Convert a Bundle to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I'd like to convert the an Intent's extras Bundle into a JSONObject so that I can pass it to/from JavaScript.

Is there a quick or best way to do this conversion? It would be alright if not all possible Bundles will work.

Comment: What are your extras?

Comment: I'm not looking to handle specific sets of extras. I'd like some general code to do it, since this codepath could be used with arbitrary data by other developers than myself.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `Bundle#keySet()` to get a list of keys that a Bundle contains. You can then iterate through those keys and add each key-value pair into a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
    try {
        // json.put(key, bundle.get(key)); see edit below
        json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(bundle.get(key)));
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        //Handle exception here
    }
}
```

Note that `JSONObject#put` will require you to catch a `JSONException`.

**Edit:**

It was pointed out that the previous code didn't handle `Collection` and `Map` types very well.  If you're using API 19 or higher, there's a `JSONObject#wrap` method that will help if that's important to you. From the [docs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#wrap%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Wrap an object, if necessary. If the object is null, return the NULL
>   object. If it is an array or collection, wrap it in a JSONArray. If it
>   is a map, wrap it in a JSONObject. If it is a standard property
>   (Double, String, et al) then it is already wrapped. Otherwise, if it
>   comes from one of the java packages, turn it into a string. And if it
>   doesn't, try to wrap it in a JSONObject. If the wrapping fails, then
>   null is returned.

Comment: This implementation doesn't seem to handle maps or lists correctly. You should check the type of the object that you get from the bundle, if it is a map you can use the new JSONObject(map) constructor, and if it is a list you can use new JSONArray(list)

Comment: Good call. If you don't want to do the checking, there's also a `JSONObject#wrap` method that will wrap it for you.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that function existed, that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Just noticed that function is only available in version 19 of the android SDK, but you can just copy that function from the source. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java

Comment: Boo. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

```
private String getJson(final Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle == null) return null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        Object obj = bundle.get(key);
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, wrap(bundle.get(key)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonObject.toString();
}

public static Object wrap(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return JSONObject.NULL;
    }
    if (o instanceof JSONArray || o instanceof JSONObject) {
        return o;
    }
    if (o.equals(JSONObject.NULL)) {
        return o;
    }
    try {
        if (o instanceof Collection) {
            return new JSONArray((Collection) o);
        } else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
            return toJSONArray(o);
        }
        if (o instanceof Map) {
            return new JSONObject((Map) o);
        }
        if (o instanceof Boolean ||
                o instanceof Byte ||
                o instanceof Character ||
                o instanceof Double ||
                o instanceof Float ||
                o instanceof Integer ||
                o instanceof Long ||
                o instanceof Short ||
                o instanceof String) {
            return o;
        }
        if (o.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("java.")) {
            return o.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}

public static JSONArray toJSONArray(Object array) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
    if (!array.getClass().isArray()) {
        throw new JSONException("Not a primitive array: " + array.getClass());
    }
    final int length = Array.getLength(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        result.put(wrap(Array.get(array, i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Gson type adapter factory that converts a Bundle to JSON.

https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters/blob/master/android/src/main/java/BundleTypeAdapterFactory.java

Answer (score 2):

If the bundle has nested bundles then `JSONObject.wrap(bundle.get(key))` will return `null`. So I managed to get it to work for my use case with this recursive function. Haven't tested more advanced use cases though.

```java
JSONObject json = convertBundleToJson(bundle);

public JSONObject convertBundleToJson(Bundle bundle) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();

    for (String key : keys) {
        try {
            if (bundle.get(key) != null && bundle.get(key).getClass().getName().equals("android.os.Bundle")) {
                Bundle nestedBundle = (Bundle) bundle.get(key);
                json.put(key, convertToJson(nestedBundle));
            } else {
                json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(bundle.get(key)));
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object myJsonObj = bundleObject.get("yourKey");
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = parser.parse(myJsonObj.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
json.get("memberInJson").getAsString();
```

Comment: I used gson because JSONObject.wrap requires Build 19. if you have an expected object just deserialized using gson. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void createFlatJSon(Bundle appRestrictions, JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException{
    for (String key : appRestrictions.keySet()) {
        if (appRestrictions.get(key) instanceof Bundle) {
           Bundle bundle = (Bundle)appRestrictions.get(key);
            Map<String, String> map = ((Bundle)appRestrictions.get(key)).keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> bundle.get(x).toString()));
            JSONObject jsonNested = new JSONObject(map);
            jsonObject.put(key,jsonNested);
            //createFlatJSon((Bundle) appRestrictions.get(key),jsonObject);
        }else if (appRestrictions.get(key) instanceof Parcelable[]){
            for (int i=0;i< ((Parcelable[]) appRestrictions.get(key)).length; i++){
                createFlatJSon((Bundle)((Parcelable[]) appRestrictions.get(key))[i],jsonObject);
            }
            //Log.e("KEY skipped",appRestrictions.get(key).toString());
        }else{
            // map = appRestrictions.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> appRestrictions.get(x).toString()));// Use this if don't want to modify the keys
            Log.e("KEY: ", key + " Value:" + appRestrictions.getString(key));
            Log.e("KEY: ", key + " Value:" + appRestrictions.get(key).getClass().getSimpleName());
            if (appRestrictions.get(key) instanceof String[]){
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (String value : (String[])appRestrictions.get(key)) {
                    jsonArray.put(value);
                }
                jsonObject.put(key,jsonArray);
            }else {
                 jsonObject.put(key, appRestrictions.get(key).toString());
            }
        }
    }


}
```