# Parse heterogeneous byte array in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, bluetooth, arrays

I'm using a cordova plugin to read data from the bluetooth stack (serial) of a BlueTherm probe. I receive the data, but then I can not make sense of it.

The JAVA native code is sending me a byte[] with the probe sent packet, which has several different data types in it, including ASCII encoded strings. The ints are little-endian. My problem is how to parse this in JavaScript. I've tried almost everything and it seems nothing cut's it.

I even may consider altering the JAVA native code to make it send only the reading, if I manage to parse the array there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I have encountered a similar situation I have natively parsed the data into a JSON object and then returned that object to JS.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, That would be a great solution. I found that, almost beating myself up, that the object is a Bundle, which is basically a key-value pair. Is there a "simple" way of parsing that thing to JSON ? I'm not a JAVA guy...

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858528/convert-a-bundle-to-json If that doesn't help, lemme know and I'll add my own answer here.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, Thanks! :) I've tried that and it kind worked. The issue here, I'm thinking, it's the communication protocol used by the BlueTherm probe. I keep receiving empty packets when I press the button... Something tells me that I have to send some command to get meaningful data. I may even have to go and "convert" an app into a cordova plugin on account of this and I do not know even where to start.

Comment: Take a look at the source of the BarcodeScanner plugin. It does something similar to what you are suggesting. Lots of activities that plug back into cordova.

Comment: Hello once again @DawsonLoudon, I'm assuming you're talking about [this one](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner). I'm examining it in preparation for my fallback plan. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure they are the same, but here is the one from PGBuild: https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/tree/9270025f71891b2f46a38b7bc3d1223b4955dce2

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that, as soon as I get back to it.