# Save WebView state in PersistableBundle

Tags: android, webview

How is it possible to save `WebView`'s state in `PersistableBundle`?

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState,
        PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    webview.restoreState((Bundle)persistentState); //Error
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState,
        PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    webview.saveState(outPersistentState); //Error
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

Or the only solution is to save it manually in preferences?

Comment: While http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598248/how-to-serialize-a-bundle is relevant, it does not answer the question, therefore this is an interesting question: how to serialize or at least persistently store a Bundle that stores the state of a webview?

Comment: Of course, you can iterate through the keyset and save it as a Json, if you so desire: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859000/2413303

Comment: Have you set the android:persistableMode to **persistAcrossReboots**?